# How to execute the function after the api call is completed in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

i am new to vue js , i have a situation  where i have to execute the function getUserViews()  after the getUser api call is completed. but looks like the getUserViews is executing before the api call is fully completed.

```
       async initUserLogin() {
    
      await this.getAccountNumber();

      if (!this.userHasDetails) {
         this.getUser();
      }

    },

    mounted() {
    this.$store.commit(types.user.setLogIn);
    this.watchBreakpoints();
    this.getUserViews();
    if (this.loginUser) {
      this.initUserLogin();
    }
},
```

Comment: your API call is probably an [asynchronous task](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), and therefore you have to [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) it's response

Comment: You are calling this.getUserViews() before the API call. Just place the function after the async call.

Comment: If you dnt mind can you show to me how to await its response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add await before `this.getUser()` (if this returns a promise)

Try also adding the get function after the async call. Then use .then(), this will be called when the request succeeded.

more info about async/await handling can be found [here](https://javascript.info/async-await)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

async initUserLogin() {
    await this.getAccountNumber();
    if (!this.userHasDetails) {
       await this.getUser(); //if this returns a promise
    }
},

mounted() {
    this.$store.commit(types.user.setLogIn);
    this.watchBreakpoints();
    if (this.loginUser) {
      this.initUserLogin().then((response) => {
        this.getUserViews();
      })
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be call after `this.getAccountNumber` but not after `this.getUser`. You miss `await` before `this.getUser();`

Comment: What does `this.getUser()` return?

Comment: Hii thomas, it returns user details

Comment: Does it return a promise?